# Numbers passed as command line arguments in python not interpreted as integers

Tags: python, argv

I am familiar with C, and have started experimenting in python. My question is regarding the `sys.argv` command. I've read it is used for a command line interpreter, but when trying to execute a simple program I don't get the results I expect.

Code:

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]

print a, b

print a+b
```

Input:

```
python mySum.py 100 200
```

Output:

```
100 200
100200
```

When I add the two arguments they are concatenated instead of the two values being added together. It seems that the values are being taken as strings.

How can I interpret them as numerics?

Comment: A similar problem would occur in C:  arguments are passed to `main()` as strings, and you would need to use `sscanf()` or `atoi()` to convert them to integers.

Comment: This is a very vague title. Can someone edit it to accurately describe the question?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can convert the arguments to integers using int()

```
import sys

a = int(sys.argv[1])  b = int(sys.argv[2])

print a, b

print a+b
```

input: `python mySum.py 100 200`

output:

```
100 200
300
```

Answer (score 15):

You also should validate the user input:

```
import sys

def is_intstring(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if not is_intstring(arg):
        sys.exit("All arguments must be integers. Exit.")

numbers = [int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:]]
sum = sum(numbers)

print "The sum of arguments is %s" % sum
```

Comment: I was about to write a new answer that says one should validate it before using int(), before I saw your answer! One can also use isdigit() that returns TRUE if all the characters in the string are (0-9).

Answer (score 14):

Indeed, you have found the problem yourself, `sys.argv` is an array of strings.

You can transform a string to an integer with `int()`. In this case for example: `a = int(sys.argv[1])`

Answer (score 5):

`sys.argv` items are always `strings`. you should cast them to `int` with `int(a)`.

You can also use third party libraries for handling CLI arguments such as [OptParse](http://wiki.python.org/moin/OptParse).

Answer (score 1):

In Python, strings are not implicitly converted to integers.
Try

```
num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
This would represent the numerical value of the number, not its string representation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of performing comparisons involving command-line arguments, which can lead to *really* unexpected behavior owing to Python 2's policy for comparing objects of different types ('int' < 'list' < 'string' < 'tuple') as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int). In Python 3, comparing objects of different types will lead to a TypeError.

For an example of object comparison mayhem, try removing the `int()` call in section 6.1.1. of the [Python tutorial Fibonacci code](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and you'll get an infinite loop, since the while loop condition becomes: 'int' < 'string'. *(This would not happen in Perl, btw).*

Great advice from @Jan-Philip above to validate command-line arguments, even for Python 3.