# How to make the output unit of tf.layers.dense variable?

Tags: tensorflow

I am a beginner of tensorflow. I would like to make the hidden layer size configurable. Let us say there is just one hidden layer, I would like

```
hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

where 'n_hidden' is

```
n_hidden = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
```

but I got a long error messages, at the end it is,

***TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'***

I searched for a while, most code examples have this output unit set by a constant or an int variable. How do I make it an configurable parameter of the program? Thanks.

Comment: as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense), u need to sent a numeric value for 'units' attribute, instead of a tensor.
Change your code to something like `n_hidden = 20` , and u would have a dense network with output dim 20.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** have it an input parameter of your program (as an int, like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751948/command-line-arguments-in-python)) but for a given graph, this parameter is fixed so it can't be a placeholder or result of another computation. If you want to change the number of hidden units, you have to recreate the graph.

Comment: Probably not a command line input parameter, but a configurable parameter that can be changed at runtime. For example, I can have a loop, iterate over a set of possible layer size, run the graph with different layer size one at a time.

Answer (score -2):

According to the documentation,

[image]

where,

units: Integer or Long, dimensionality of the output space.

In your code, **n_hidden** should specify the number of units in the hidden layer. Therefore, it should be a number, not a tensor. Therefore, **tf.layers.dense** creates the hidden layer according to the number of units specified.